# Fair price to charge for editing out photobombers

Tags: photo-editing

Someone has the perfect family photo but there are people photobombing or just there in the background. What would be a fair price to get out the extra people and reconstruct the background?

Comment: How can anyone answer this? Where are you even? Is editing photos your "9 to 5" job? Charge what you charge everyone else. Charge what your time and skill are worth. Charge what you would be happy to be offered.

Comment: Related: How much to charge for photobombing on demand in order to sell edits ;) (no accusation meant, just being funny!)

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/PhotoshopRequest/ is full of people willing to do it for free - but also shows what people charge/pay for similar services.

Comment: (Said slowly, and with gravitas) "One. Million. Dollars."

Comment: @martha Pesos? Rubles? Yen? US Dollars? Euros? Pounds Sterling? Shekels? Dinar? Francs? Rupee? Yuan Renminbi? Wampum?

Comment: I prefer the reverse approach: find some people with pictures, and threaten to edit in more photobombers unless they pay you.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would be a fair price to get out the extra people and reconstruct the background?

There's nothing here that's particularly different from other kinds of work. Charge your hourly rate times the number of hours you spend on the project, rounded to the nearest tenth or quarter hour or whatever. If materials or travel are involved (like going to the location to reshoot the background), factor those in.

It's often hard to know how to set a price when you're starting out in a business, and it's natural to low-ball the price in order to please the customer. But think: if the customer says "That's great! At that price, I've got a hundred more that I'd like you to do!" would you be happy to do all that work at the same price? If not, your price is probably too low.